# Select individual columns in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How do I select individual columns instead of doing `select l`?

```
IEnumerable<LEA> query = default(IEnumerable<LEA>);

var query = from l in bModel.leas
            join la in bModel.LondonAreas on l.LEANo equals la.LeaNo
            where la.AreaNo == areaNo
            select l;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous Objects is the way to select specific columns

```
IEnumerable<LEA> query = default(IEnumerable<LEA>);

var query = from l in bModel.leas
    join la in bModel.LondonAreas on l.LEANo equals la.LeaNo
    where la.AreaNo == areaNo
    select new
    {
        LEANo = l.LEANo,
        AreaNo = la.AreaNo
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous object in the 'select' portion of the query that contains the properties you need.

Like so:

```
IEnumerable<LEA> query = default(IEnumerable<LEA>);

var query = from l in bModel.leas
            join la in bModel.LondonAreas on l.LEANo equals la.LeaNo
            where la.AreaNo == areaNo
            select new { LEANo = l.LEANo };
```